# How to detect MKAnnotationView / MKMarkerAnnotationView first and second click?

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

When you click on a marker on the mapview, the marker grows. That's the first click. On second click it returns to the original size.

[image]

I was able to detect the first click with MKMapViewDelegate function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {}
```

Is there a way to detect the second click? Check something in the function above or with a different function?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452707-mapview ?

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah this could help, but the problem is that, this action executes even when i press somewhere else. I need an action when you click again on the marker, when its in its bigger state.

Comment: You may need to create your own annotation view subclass